# Can't calculate raster using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, raster-calculator, merge

So I'm new to QGIS (2 days) but have spent *HOURS* on it everyday trying to learn it to process raw SRTM data make 3D relief maps on another software, so I can work my way around it but can't really do any of the coding. Therefore, please consider that if your answer will refer to coding. The files I'm using are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-J5jn_y_0sLf2ChVAb4U32cZ6xFirejX?usp=sharing)

I downloaded the SRTM images (98 tiles), merged them into one, reprojected them, and now I want to use the following raster calculation on them: (Pixel Value + 23) ÷ 1244 * 65535. 65535 is because it's a 16-bit TIFF and the other values have to do with the range of pixel values in the merged STRM map. This is to avoid terracing in the 3D relief map when created in the other software and to get rid of negative values.

When I try and run the calculation, it gives me this error:
*"The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/dell/OneDrive - UOM/Blender/Map Making/QGIS Files/UK/SRTM Map Scaled.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm."*

The calculation would work and create a raster if I'm using one of the downloaded SRTM files as the 'reference layer', but that obviously doesn't give the right extent and projection. It gives the error I copied when using the reprojected, clipped or merged layers. I've tried doing the calculation in a new project file with no luck.

Comment: Did you "check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information"? What does it say?

Comment: @Babel It doesn't say anything there. If I don't put a reference layer, it updates saying there's no reference but when I put the reference layers I need, it just doesn't update. I'm considering starting over and seeing if that works.

Comment: Your workflow is not completely clear to me, so it' s difficult to give any advice. Why, for example, do you merge all rasters? How should your output look? If you just want to create a relief, it does not make sense.

Comment: @Babel The area I'm interested in needs multiple rasters. I'm making the relief on a  3D computer graphics software so I need it to be a single file to make things much easier and to have the image contrasts in the right proportion to each other. The output should pretty much look the same but the computer graphics software can't read negative pixel values (i.e. below sea level) so this calculation gets rid of them and also stretches the pixel values all across the 65,535 values in the 16bit TIFF; this is to prevent terracing caused by rounding. Hope this helps

Comment: @Seif - I did the raster calculation successfully on your test file in QGIS 3.12 using both the Raster -> Raster Calculator... and GDAL >> Raster Miscellaneous >> Raster Calculator, and got no errors either time. In both cases my output type was Float32. So it seems unlikely your problem is QGIS-specific.

Comment: @TomBrennan Thanks for taking the time to answer. I eventually tried using the GDAL calculator and it worked fine so that's what I've been using for the past couple weeks. Appreciate your response.